# What is a good way to browse old questions?

Tags: support

There are a lot of great old questions and it's fun to browse through them sometimes, but I have yet to find a good way to do it.

I can start at the first page and work backwards, or start at page 12200 and work forward. Is there a way I can look at say page 3141 without having to click to it a few pages at a time? I've done this a couple times working forward from the end, but now I have seen the questions toward the end, and would have to click quite far up the list until I get to questions I haven't seen yet. This is frustrating.

I've noticed that a couple badges such as "Excavator" and "Archaeologist" depend on editing or answering old questions so it seems like there should be an easy way to look up posts 6 months or older, or from 2012 etc.

Are there any such filters somewhere? How do I access old questions without starting from the oldest? Thanks!

Comment: Search within tags that interest you.

Comment: `http://math.stackexchange.com/questions?page=XXXX&sort=newest` In general, when you click for the first time to go to the next page, the `page=XXXX` part appears in the URL. Change it to search quickly.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen True, that helps, but some tags still have 1000+ pages, and its hard to get to the middle of them.

Comment: @Lord_Farin Oh good one! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for questions to answer, try Data Explorer query [Find interesting unanswered questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/4038/find-interesting-unanswered-questions?UserId=188658). It gives a list of well-received unanswered questions tailored to your interests. (I filled in your User Id for demonstration)

If you are looking for things to read, try search parameters such as [is:q intags:mine created:60m](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aq%20intags%3amine%20created%3a60m). This search returns all questions with your favorite tags asked during a particular month (I used 60 months ago as an example), sorted by votes.  This query can also be adapted to finding questions without an answer, by adding `answers:0` parameter.

References: [search parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching), [Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/help).